# Tar files older than n days

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script which will tar log and zip files older than 180 days and remove them.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=()
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    files+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find /mnt/main/var/www/m2allcrm/ -maxdepth 1 -mtime +180 -type f \( -name "*.log" -o -name "*.csv" \) -print0)
name=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
tar cvfz "backup_$name.tar.gz "${files[@]}"
```

When I run it, I get error :

```
syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

[image]

**Could anyone help me to debug this error and also remove the files?**

*Thanks!!*

Comment: `done < <` spacing not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tar's option `--files-from` handles whitespace in filenames, filename `-` means `stdin`.

Hence a simpler version:

```
name=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
find /mnt/main/var/www/m2allcrm/ -maxdepth 1 -mtime +180 -type f \( -name "*.log" -o -name "*.csv" \) | tar cvzf backup_$name.tar.gz --files-from -
```